# How to find back the article structure of the latex extension in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I accidentally close the file structure of `TEX` extension, and how can I find it back?

Like the picture below shows, I only have `COMMANDS` and `SNIPPED VIEW` now, how can I find back the file structure item?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your talking about the LaTeX Workshop Extension.

You can hide and un-hide the different tabs in your extension in two ways.

Either left-click on the three dots next to *LATEX* on the top of the extension view and set a checkmark at *Sructure*

[image: Selection of shown tabs on top of extension view]

Or right-click one of the remaining tabs and set a checkmark at *Structure*
[image: Selection of shown tabs on remaining tabs]

Comment: I found it in the `terminal`, thanks!

Comment: @narip can you explain to me how to do that? I would like to add that to the answer

Comment: I accidentally move the `Structure` to the side bar, and then by clicking on `tex` button on the right panel, I change `tex` `Move Views to Panel`, which is on the button of the editor. Originally I didn't find it in the button. Now I just find it.

Comment: '' *I found it in the `terminal`*'', in fact, I find it in the panel area next to `terminal`.